# How to make a URL link to another state of the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to share a page in a state when the second link is active (e.g. "http:/ /mypage#green-color").

I tried to add to the second link `onClick="window.location='#green-color';"` attribute. It changes the URL in the browser's address window, but I can't share it with others.

[code in JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rk3Xz/1/)

```
<a href="#" id="all">All Colors</a>
<a href="#green" id="green-color">Green Color</a>
<div id="red"></div>
<div id="green"></div>
```

Two states of the page:

```
$( "#all" ).click(function() {
  $( "#red" ).show(200);
});
$( "#green-color" ).click(function() {
  $( "#red" ).hide(200);
});
```

Comment: `share it with others`part is confusing...not clear at all what you mean

Comment: I would like to have separate URL for the second link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try passing divId in Url

like this

```
onClick="window.location='#green';"
```

And for for effects use `window.location.hash` method.

```
var hashValue=window.location.hash;
if(hashValue=="#green")
{
 $( "#red" ).hide(200);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand but see my HARD CODE solution:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(document.URL == 'http://mypage#green-color'){
         $( "#red" ).hide(200);   
    }
    else
    {
         $( "#red" ).show(200);
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect what you want is to be able to change the state of page when you clcik on a hashed link

hash is the part of url prefixed with `#`.

You can retrieve the hash on page load using `location.hash` then do whatever state changes you want on page load based on hash value. Not clear at all in question what you are wanting to do.